# If I install passenger via tarball and install it, how do I uninstall it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

Normally I would install phusion passenger via the gem command, but this wouldn't work for me, so I had to install it via a tarball and then run the installer.

My question is, how do I uninstall it?

```
dpkg -l | grep passenger
```

doesn't return anything. When I list the installed gems, I don't see anything either.

So i guess I have two questions
    1) If installed by tarball/installer, how to uninstall
    2) If I came upon this system, how could I even *tell* that passenger is installed? It doesn't seem to show up anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read what the [Passenger documentation has to say about removal.](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#_installing_upgrading_and_uninstalling_phusion_passenger)

The only guaranteed indicator of a passenger installation is the passenger file in the apache configuration. Usually `/etc/apache2/conf.d/passenger`. You must remove it, and then uninstall passenger in a method dependent on how it was installed.

If installed from a gem:

```
# gem uninstall passenger
```

If installed from a tarball:

remove the installation directory, Which is noted as the PassengerRoot directive in the aforementioned configuration file.

If installed form a deb file:

```
# sudo apt-get remove libapache2-mod-passenger
```

Answer (score 2):

You just remove the folder it was installed to, and thats it.

Comment: okay, second part. If you came upon a system that you didn't build. How could to check to see that passenger was installed? if it was installed by tarball.

And is it really that easy to uninstall, just remove the folder? I'm assuming the installer did all sorts of stuff? Don't I need to undo all the things the install did?

Comment: There isn't anything inside a "hidden" folder like you are thinking. If it was installed by the package manager, they contain the same exact files, just easier to uninstall (a single command to remove the files).